# sybase date comparison to get results from other table

Tags: datetime, comparison, sybase

I have two tables that contents as below :
TABLE 1 :

```
REFER_Id| Name   |   Registered_Date(YYYYMMDD)
1       | PERK   |   20050101
2       | SANDRA |   20061201
3       | PETER  |   20070515
```

TABLE 2 :

```
Student_ID| NAME | REFER_ID | RENEW_Date(YYYYMMDD)
1         | Sam  |  1       | 20050501
1         | Sam  |  1       | 20051225
2         | Jenny|  2       | 20060324
2         | Jenny|  2       | 20060624
2         | Jenny|  2       | 20071224
3         | Perk |  3       | 20071224
```

Scenario: Every student_id is connected with REFER_Id and every student should renew his details every few months.

Now I need get the last updated RENEW_Date of each student and compare with RENEW_Date(TABLE2) vs Registered_date(TABLE1) and get the REFER_ID whose difference is greater than 12months and less than 12months. I need to compare based on months.

Really appreciate for your help.
Thank you.

Comment: renew_date is 'VARCHAR` or 'INT'? Assuming you can write the query by yourself, use `CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), RENEW_Date), 112)` to convert renew_date to a valid date

Comment: Can you give more details? What should the output look like in the above example? What does it mean when you say - **REFER_ID whose difference is greater than 12months and less than 12months**